# Indexes out of range in selection sort algorithm

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

Regarding Selection Sort Algorithm. Let's assume that my array has 10 elements. If I leave `len()` and remove the `-1` in the loop that belongs to the `selection_sort()` function I get that in the last iteration that `i` will be equal to 9. So we pass that value to the `select()` function and it is gonna start with `j=10`, and there is no such a thing. The program should rise an error since there is no such thing as `if array[9] > array[10]`, `array[10]` does not exist, instead, the program shows the array sorted. Why doesn't the program rise an error?

```
def select(array, start):
    minIndex = start

    for j in range(start + 1, len(array)):
        if array[minIndex] > array[j]:
            minIndex = j

def selection_sort(array):
    
   # If I put len(array) removing the -1, I get it sort it anyway
    for i in range(len(array) - 1 ): # Here, I do not get it
        minIndex = select(array, i)
        tmp = array[i]
        array[i] = array[minIndex]
        array[minIndex] = tmp
```

**Output**:

```
Unsorted array: [9, 7, 3, 10, 2, 6, 4, 5, 8, 1]

Iteration i =  0
Iteration j =  1
Iteration j =  2
Iteration j =  3
Iteration j =  4
Iteration j =  5
Iteration j =  6
Iteration j =  7
Iteration j =  8
Iteration j =  9
[1, 7, 3, 10, 2, 6, 4, 5, 8, 9]
Iteration i =  1
Iteration j =  2
Iteration j =  3
Iteration j =  4
Iteration j =  5
Iteration j =  6
Iteration j =  7
Iteration j =  8
Iteration j =  9
[1, 2, 3, 10, 7, 6, 4, 5, 8, 9]
Iteration i =  2
Iteration j =  3
Iteration j =  4
Iteration j =  5
Iteration j =  6
Iteration j =  7
Iteration j =  8
Iteration j =  9
[1, 2, 3, 10, 7, 6, 4, 5, 8, 9]
Iteration i =  3
Iteration j =  4
Iteration j =  5
Iteration j =  6
Iteration j =  7
Iteration j =  8
Iteration j =  9
[1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 6, 10, 5, 8, 9]
Iteration i =  4
Iteration j =  5
Iteration j =  6
Iteration j =  7
Iteration j =  8
Iteration j =  9
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 7, 8, 9]
Iteration i =  5
Iteration j =  6
Iteration j =  7
Iteration j =  8
Iteration j =  9
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 10, 7, 8, 9]
Iteration i =  6
Iteration j =  7
Iteration j =  8
Iteration j =  9
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 10, 8, 9]
Iteration i =  7
Iteration j =  8
Iteration j =  9
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 9]
Iteration i =  8
Iteration j =  9
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
Iteration i =  9
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>>
```

Comment: When you do range(n), It takes values from 0 to n-1. So in your last iteration, it will be array[8] > array[8]

Comment: @LazyCoder I said "what if I remove the `-1` from the `for` loop that belongs to the second function. So in that case we would have `for i in range(len(array))`, thus if the array has 10 elements it goes from 0 to 9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python's `range` includes the `start` argument in the range, but excludes the `stop` argument.

This means that if `start` and `stop` are the same, the range will be empty. This is the case in your example if you call `select` with a list of length 10 and `start = 9`. The `for` loop in `select` is then equivalent to:

```
for j in range(10, 10):
```

and since `range(10, 10)` is empty, the loop will never execute.

So `array[10]` never happens, and no `IndexError` is raised.

Comment: Cool but the range structure is `range(start, n-1), thus `len(array)` is 10. Then range would go `range(10, 10-1)`

Comment: @NaveganTeX the answer refers to the `range` in the `select` function, not the one in `selection_sort`. The `range` in `selection_sort` would be `range(0, 9)`, in your given example

Comment: incidentally, `range(10, 10-1)` would also be an empty range

Comment: I am referring myself to the range in the `select` function!

Comment: To conclude, and taking into account what you said in the last comment, in the `select` function we would get `range(10, 9)`.

Comment: @NaveganTeX if your `selection_sort` range is `range(len(array))` then your last `select` range is `range(10, 10)`. If your `selection_sort` range is `range(len(array)-1)` then your last `select` range is `range(10, 9)`.

Comment: This makes absolute sense. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

If you put a print statement inside your loop in your `select` function, you'll see that `j` is never assigned the value 10. Since you can replace the code by `for j in range(10, 10)` the loop is never executed.

Try it with this

```
def select(array, start):
    minIndex = start
    print("Start", start)

    for j in range(start + 1, len(array)):
        print(j)
        if array[minIndex] > array[j]:
            minIndex = j

    return minIndex
```

I assumed that you need to return `minIndex` at the end of your function, since you assign it inside `selection_sort`.

You can also try this code to see that it just return an empty list

```
print(list(range(10, 10)))
```